# How to use @fontawesome social network icons on angular 7?

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I can use Font Awesome's icons on angular 7 using this instruction - https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started. But it's impossible to import faFacebook, faTwitter, and other social networks icons from `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons`.

Comment: All of those icons are available in the 'brand' npm package, so instead of using `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons`, you should be using `@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @peinearydevelopment comment, added new package `@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons` and this is solution.

Answer (score 1):

yes with the **awesome/free-brands-svg-icons** we can display the icons in the angular.We can install it with the help of npm as **npm  install awesome/free-brands-svg-icons** explicity

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please elaborate more instead of just saying "install the library"